# revert to older version of the default video player

Tags: video

I recent re-installed Ubuntu 16.04, and I don't like the version of the default video player. I would like to install the older version because 1) it allowed me to start the videos where I left off, instead of starting over at the beginning, and 2) it was easier to create and view playlists.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can check what versions are available to you with `sudo apt-cache madison ^packagename`

Replace "packagename" with the package you're trying to downgrade.

Then, `sudo apt-get remove packagename`

Then install the package with the version you want:

`sudo apt-get install packagename=1.2\*`

Replace the version number with the one you want. Using the \* is a wildcard for subversions. Or you can copy the entire version from the list that the first command gave you.

Comment: It looks like the only package that was available is the current one. Is there a way to obtain an older version of totem?